# Clarification needed:Limit of sum of two functions

Tags: limits

I am having a small conceptual problem.

When we are calculating limits of the form

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{h(x)}$$

under what conditions can we write it as

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{h(x)}+\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$$ ?

My teacher said that such a conversion is not always valid and we might get wrong results.So my question is when is such a conversion valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is valid when both of the limits
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{h(x)}\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}
$$
exist (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Properties)). This fact is often called the algebraic limit theorem.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta You're welcome!